# I want to change the div height by hovering on the text INSIDE the div

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I have a outer div named `Title` which has `style="width=100%"`
and inner div named `more`

So I want to change height of outer div by hovering on inner div(smoothly.. using transition)

Is it possible using css??

I want something like

```
transition: height .4s;
-moz-transition: height .4s; 
-webkit-transition: height .4s; 
-o-transition: height .4s;  
-ms-transition: height .4s;
```

my title css code

```
#title{
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#000;
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
    right:20px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    height:42px;
    min-width:800px;
}
```

My more css code

```
#more{
    padding-left:10px;
    color:#999;
    text-decoration:underline;
    font-size:10px;
}
```

All the below code are not working

- `name:hover #title{height:200px}`
- `name:hover + #title{height:200px}`
- `name:hover ~ #title{height:200px}`
- `name:hover > #title{height:200px}`

can i do it through JavaScript???

Comment: For future reference: [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: I modified my answer, to provide some hints on how to solve the problem. If you want more info just ask;)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot target an ancestor element in css without using the **[Subject Identifier](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#subject)** which is introduced in [CSS Selectors Level 4 Draft](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/) which is supported by none of the browsers at the moment.

In farther future you can write (the exclamation mark is a temporary solution):

```
!#Title name:hover{
    /* css stuff */
}
```

You can however do one of the following things:

Declare `display:table` on your `#title` div and animate the `#more` div like in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2RwB/1/). Works at least in chrome;)

Or you just use javascript (or perhaps jQuery), apply an eventhandler and either modify the height of `#title` directly or apply a class holding the transition effect.

Comment: yes, however this might not work smoothly in all browsers. A javascript solution might be preferable here. This however depends on what exactly you want/need. Did this solve your problem?